# Remove mysql database entry in background with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a query that generating a list of records:

```
<table class="simplet" width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="300" colspan="2">Product Name</th>
<th width="150">Brand</th>
<th width="100">Quantity</th>
<th width="60">Price</th>
<th width="30">Delete</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td colspan="6"><div id="status_text_list" /></td></tr>

[insert_php]

$current_user= wp_get_current_user();
$username= $current_user->user_login;

mysql_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxx");//database connection
mysql_select_db(xxx");

$query= "SELECT * FROM wp_userdata WHERE username='$username'";
$result= mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) { die("Error db request: <br />". mysql_error()); }

while ($result_row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){ echo '<tr class="odd-row"><td width="30"></td><td>'.$result_row['product_name'].'</td><td>'.$result_row['product_brand'].'</td><td>'.$result_row['product_quantity'].'</td><td>'.$result_row['product_link'].'</td><td><a class="link-delete" href="delete.php?id='.$result_row['id'].'">X</a></td></tr>';
}


[/insert_php]

</tbody></table>
```

Here is my ajax jquery part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//on the click of the submit button 
$(".link-delete").click(function(){
 //get the form values


var current_user= wp_get_current_user();
var username= $current_user->user_login;

 //make the postdata
 var postData = 'username='+username;

 //call your input.php script in the background, when it returns it will call the success function if the request was successful or the error one if there was an issue (like a 404, 500 or any other error status)

 $.ajax({
    url : "delete.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : postData,
    success: function(data,status, xhr)
    {
        //if success then just output the text to the status div then clear the form inputs to prepare for new data
        $("#status_text_list").html(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown)
    {
        //if fail show error and server status
        $("#status_text_list").html('there was an error ' + errorThrown + ' with status ' + textStatus);
    }
});
}); });
```

And here is my delete.php:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxx");//database connection
mysql_select_db("xxxx");


if(isset($_REQUEST['id']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['id']))
{
mysql_query("DELETE FROM wp_userdata WHERE id='".$_REQUEST['id']."'");
}

echo ("DATA DELETED SUCCESSFULLY");
```

This list of records has a delete "X" link at the end of each table row. When I click on the delete link, i need the deletion process to be done in background without leaving the page.

As of right now when I click delete it brings me to delete.php page. The records gets deleted though.

So how do I make the Ajax part to work?

Also is it possible to have a deleted row to disappear from the screen as well without leaving/refreshing the page?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thanks for Mysqli tutorial! Now, how about Ajax-Jquery-deletion tutorial? Maybe this way we will stay on the topic?

Comment: @esqew Seems you copy and paste that comment in every question that uses `mysql_*`. You are right, though. The OP should take note of it.

Comment: @afaolek A lot of my comments in the PHP tag consist of this warning, but it's very important that the OP **as well as future visitors** to this question know that this extension shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: I am more concerned about ajax functionality here, when I get that part working, I'll focus on the modernising my mysql. This is not what this post is about, you cant expect everyone come here with a perfectly validated and optimized code for every question?

Comment: I'm fully aware that's not what the question is about, but it's still very important. This is not an attempt at answering your question, which is why I have placed it in the comments section.

Comment: I am just surprised you didn't hit me with your "Don't use tables in webdesign" cut-&-paste template, I guess some things can get let go with time? ;)

Comment: Don't you both think you are taking it too far? @esqew you have made a good point and I believe Acidon understands you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There are multiple issues with this code.

1. You're mixing Javascript and PHP.

   ```
   var current_user= wp_get_current_user();
   var username= $current_user->user_login;
   ```

   You're attempting to create Javascript variables from PHP calls. This **won't** work. You might be looking for something akin to:

   ```
   <?php
   $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
   echo "var username = '" . $current_user->user_login . "'";
   ?>
   ```
2. You're getting re-directed because you are using `a` nodes with an `href` attribute set. The behavior by default, is to take the browser to that new page.

   Make the `href` value `#` and let the jQuery `$.click()` hook do the heavy lifting, as you have written it to do.
3. Your AJAX function calls `delete.php`, but with no `$_GET` attribute indicating the ID.

   When generating your table, give the `a` tag that calls the AJAX function a custom `data-*` attribute containing the ID to delete.

   ```
   <a class="link-delete" href="#" data-delete-id="' . $result_row['id'] . '">X</a>
   ```

   You can access this `data-*` variable by modifying your `$.click()` function with something like:

   ```
   $(".link-delete").click(function(){
    var deleteid = $(this).data("delete-id");
    //big snip
    $.ajax({
       url : "delete.php?id="+deleteid,
       //big snip
     });
   });
   ```
4. While outside the scope of the question, this code utilizes the deprecated PHP `mysql_*` extension. Please consider switching to MySQLi or PDO for your database code.
5. While also outside the scope of the question, it appears that you are vulnerable to SQL injection. This is a major security risk and is easily mitigated by utilizing prepared queries, available in both the extensions suggested as alternatives to the `mysql_*` extension.

---

**Update**: At this point, you're going to want to remove the row from the view. You can do this by using jQuery's convenient `$.closest()` directive.
    $(".link-delete").click(function(){
     //big snip
     $.ajax({
        //snip
        success: function(data,status, xhr)
        {
            //if success then just output the text to the status div then clear the form inputs to prepare for new data
            $("#status_text_list").html(data);
            $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // remove parent  after successful deletion
        },
        //snip again
      });
    });

Comment: @Acidon My apologies, it appears I've forgotten that hyphenated variables aren't accepted in Javascript (they are interpreted as subtraction). I've updated my answer.

Comment: ok I've applied the updated version but still no luck - http://suppliesprices.com/?page_id=4 , looks like the delete link looks strange in the browser. I also changed `echo "var username=\"".$current_user->user_login."\";";` part to produce `var username="admin";` string

Comment: **Look at your Javascript console.** `SyntaxError: missing } after property list suppliesprices.com:69`. You have made a typo by declaring `url:` twice. (The delete link does not look any different for me using Firefox 31, that is a CSS issue for a different question).

Comment: Awwww, its working!!!! is there a way to delete corresponding displayed row from the screen in real time without refreshing?

Comment: Yes. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: ahh, you are the best, now after its done, Ill head straight to MySQli tutorials you've suggested to update my code

Comment: Added the use of the `$.parent()` directive to remove the deleted row from the DOM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59214/discussion-between-acidon-and-esqew).

Comment: @Acidon check my message in chat. The directive is `$.closest()`, not `$.nearest()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.preventDefault();`. Edit your code like this

```
$(".link-delete").click(function(e){   // Note the e parameter
    e.preventDefault();                // NOTE THIS
    // get the form values
    // and so on and so forth
```

**EDIT**

I don't know but I just saw this part of the code:

```
$(".link-delete").click(function(){
    var deleteid = $(this).data("delete-id");
    //big snip
    $.ajax({
        url : "delete.php?id="+deleteid,
    //big snip
    });
});
```

Using my old code now works (at least in my browser):

```
$(".link-delete").click(function(e){   // Note the e parameter
    e.preventDefault();                // NOTE THIS
    var deleteid = $(this).data("delete-id");
    // etc
```

Hopefully, it should work on your side, too.

Comment: I changed but it still gets redirected, here is the page http://suppliesprices.com/?page_id=4

Comment: i tried changing but it doesn't delete anything, nothing happens